# C# Array.Find search

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

I want to search from the array. This is my code

```
string[] Main_Events = { "Five Ships In The Harbour", "Australia Day", "Christmas", "New Years", "The Melbourne Cup", "Australian Open Tennis" };
string search_str = "Australia Day";

string value1 = Array.Find(Main_Events, element => element.Contains(search_str));
```

The search works fine if i search `Australia Day` but if the search is `The Australia Day`. The value of `value1` is `null`.

How can i search if the search value is `The Australia Day` and in the array the value is `Australia Day` then the value of `value1` should be `Australia Day or true.`

I am using `Array.Find` because i want to search from 5 different arrays. Like `Main_Events`, i have four other arrays.

Thanks in advance

Comment: For custom search you have to create your own extension `search` method. I think you know why it is returning `null` on `The Australia Day`.

Comment: ok so do you mean i should use foreach to compare the values but i was using this because i have to search through 5 different arrays and then writing 5 foreach loops to search will increase the code thats why i use array.find

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need the array node value to be equal to or a substring of the given string then you can change the search to below:

```
var value1 = Array.Find(mainEvents, element => searchStr.Contains(element));
```

You can change accordingly for case insensitive comparison(by converting to uppercase).

Answer (score 1):

Try to search `element` in `search_str`:

```
string value1 = Array.Find(Main_Events, element => element.Contains(search_str) || search_str.Contains(element));
```

Comment: Its not a generic solution. Suppose he have Football Cup and Tennis Cup.  Guess what happens when you try to find 'Cup'. Also its depends on the requirement and input though :)

Comment: in such a case just use FindAll the solution will work fine .             var value1 = Array.FindAll(Main_Events, element => element.Contains(search_str) || search_str.Contains(element));

Comment: @WaqarAhmed yes, it depends, but it may be an option

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] Main_Events = { "Five Ships In The Harbour", "Australia Day", "Christmas", "New Years", "The Melbourne Cup", "Australian Open Tennis" };
string search_str = "The Australia Day";

List<string> search_strs = search_str.Split(null).Where(s => s != string.Empty).ToList();
if (search_strs.Count > 0)
{                  
    List<string> searchResult = Main_Events.Where(x => search_strs.Any(keyword => (x).Contains(keyword))).ToList();                                                                   
}
```